# Call C funcion from Tibco bw6

Tags: c, integration, tibco, tibco-business-works

I have existing C program which i want to call from tibco bw6. Is there any direct approach, like bw allow to invoke java code.

One possible solution is to use java invoke and jni. Direct call will be more preferable if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the .exe file you can use External Command activity otherwise I do not see any other simple solutions than to use swig with jni.

Regards